# Python - While True: Try Except Else - Program Flow Question

Tags: python, while-loop, try-except

I have this code using a `While True` with a `try catch`. The final else statement is always being executed when the 'try' is successful and I'd like to understand why - I think I'm not understanding the program flow correctly.

```py
while True:
    try:
        subprocess.call(["wget", "-O", "splunk-8.0.1-6db836e2fb9e-Linux-x86_64.tgz", "https://www.splunk.com/bin/splunk/DownloadActivityServlet?architecture=x86_64&platform=linux&version=8.0.1&product=splunk&filename=splunk-8.0.1-6db836e2fb9e-Linux-x86_64.tgz&wget=true"])
        print("successfully downloaded splunk enterprise")
        time.sleep(2)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 2:
            print(e)
            print("wget doesn't seem to be installed")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("attempting to install wget")
            time.sleep(2)
            subprocess.call(["yum", "install", "wget"])
        else:
            print(e)
            print("unknown error response, exiting...")
            break
    else:
        print("something else went wrong while trying to download splunk")
        break
```

Comment: Fix indentation. Right now it's a syntax error.

Comment: `while`, `try`, and `if` *all* can take an `else` clause. Indentation determines which one your `else` clause is actually associated with. With the `try` statement, it's executed if there were no exceptions.

Comment: That's how try-except-else-finally blocks work. You try something. If there's an error, you catch (or 'except' in python) it, otherwise (i.e. "else") do something else. "Finally" you clean up at the end.

Comment: As an aside, you should be ensuring that `wget` is installed *before* you run your code. If it's not installed, just exit; your script shouldn't be installing its own dependencies. For all it knows, `wget` is already installed, just not in the location your code expects.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` clause of a `try` executes if the code inside the `try` did *not* throw an exception.  If you want to catch any exception, use `except` without specifying an exception class:

```
except:
    print("something else went wrong while trying to download splunk")
    break
```

However, consider just omitting this piece of code.  As it is currently written, it doesn't tell you *what* went wrong.  If you remove these lines, you will get an error message that tells you what happened and on which line the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

based on [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), try-except can take an optional else statement:

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

so based on this, your else statement will run if codes in try doesn't raise any exception!

what you want is another except clause that catches a general exceptation, so you just need to replace `else` with `except`:

```
while True:
    try:
        subprocess.call(["wget", "-O", "splunk-8.0.1-6db836e2fb9e-Linux-x86_64.tgz", "https://www.splunk.com/bin/splunk/DownloadActivityServlet?architecture=x86_64&platform=linux&version=8.0.1&product=splunk&filename=splunk-8.0.1-6db836e2fb9e-Linux-x86_64.tgz&wget=true"])
        print("successfully downloaded splunk enterprise")
        time.sleep(2)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 2:
            print(e)
            print("wget doesn't seem to be installed")
            time.sleep(2)
            print("attempting to install wget")
            time.sleep(2)
            subprocess.call(["yum", "install", "wget"])
        else:
            print(e)
            print("unknown error response, exiting...")
            break
    except:
        print("something else went wrong while trying to download splunk")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception.

So the else clause will run if the code within the try block runs successfully.